# Loop through multiple dictionary items to analyze denoising combinations using wavelets

Tags: python, matlab, loops, wavelet

thanks in advance for any help.

I am trying to analyze and plot all possible combinations for wavelet denoising in Python using function that mimic Matlab wavelet functions. This involves four different variables, and iterates between all of them. I am unsure if appending and looping through dictionary values is possible. Any advice on how to do this? Below is what I have tried.

```
    threshold = {'rigrsure','heursure','sqtwolog','minimaxi'}
    sorh = {'hard','soft'}
    scal = {'one', 'sln', 'mln'}

     for k in pywt.wavelist(kind='discrete'):
         name = k
         w = pywt.Wavelet(name)
         n = pywt.dwt_max_level(len(A), w.dec_len)
     for l in threshold:
        thres = l
        print(thres)
     for j in sorh:
         sorh = j
         print(sorh)
     for i in scal:
        scal = i
        print(scal)

         A_denoised = wden(A, thr, sorh, scal, n, name)
         plt.plot(A, color='blue')
         plt.plot(A_denoised, color='red', label=[name,l,j,i])
         plt.legend(loc='upper right')
         plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Update: I was able to solve the problem by changing the name of the variables within the loop.

```
    threshold = {'rigrsure','heursure','sqtwolog','minimaxi'}
    sorh = {'hard','soft'}
    scal = {'one', 'sln', 'mln'}

    for k in pywt.wavelist(kind='discrete'):
        name = k
        w = pywt.Wavelet(name)
        n = pywt.dwt_max_level(len(A), w.dec_len)
        for l in threshold:
            thres = l
            for j in sorh:
               sh = j
                for i in scal:
                    scale = i
                    A_denoised = wden(A, thres, sh, scale, n, name)
                    plt.plot(A, color='blue')
                    plt.plot(A_denoised, color='red', label=[name,l,j,i])
                    plt.legend(loc='upper right')
                    plt.show()
```